# Unity3D Cycle through scenes in play mode and check objects for components in them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so i'm trying to write a script which loops through all scenes and finds witch objects have more than one 2D collider. I already wrote the script and it works fine while the game is not in play mode, but some scripts add a collider component in Start() or in other places and there are over 100 scenes.

Is there a way that an editor script can start play mode, loop through all scenes (load scene 0, wait for it to load, check all objects then move on to the next scene).

Already written script here:

```
 14 public class SearchForDoubleColliders : EditorWindow
 15 {
 16     [MenuItem("CustomTools/Search For Double Colliders")]
 17     static void Init()
 18     {
 19         SearchForDoubleColliders window = (SearchForDoubleColliders)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(SearchForDoubleColliders));
 20         window.titleContent = new GUIContent("Search For Double Colliders");
 21         window.Show();
 22         window.position = new Rect(50, 80, 1200, 500);
 23 
 24         
 25     }
 26 
 27     Vector2 scroll;
 28     List<string> listResult = new List<string>();
 29     static string[] scenesPathNames; 
 30     string[] scenesNames;
 31     public List<GameObject> objectsList;
 32 
 33 
 34     void OnGUI()
 35     {
 36         GUILayout.Space(3);
 37         int oldValue = GUI.skin.window.padding.bottom;
 38         GUI.skin.window.padding.bottom = -20;
 39         Rect windowRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(1, 17);
 40         windowRect.x += 4;
 41         windowRect.width -= 7;
 42         GUI.skin.window.padding.bottom = oldValue;
 43         GUILayout.Label("Make sure to build the project before running the search!");
 44         GUILayout.Space(10);
 45         GUILayout.BeginVertical();
 46         GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
 47         //createLog = GUILayout.Toggle(createLog, "Create build asset log in /Assets/Assets_in_build.txt?");
 48         GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
 49         GUILayout.EndVertical();
 50         GUILayout.Space(10);
 51         if (GUILayout.Button("Search!"))
 52         {
 53             Debug.LogWarning("Searching... Will take some time...");
 54             //EditorApplication.isPlaying = true;
 55             DoSearch();
 56         }
 57 
 58         if (listResult != null)
 59         {
 60             GUILayout.BeginVertical();
 61             GUILayout.Space(10);
 62             GUILayout.Label("Found " + listResult.Count + " objects with double colliders in the build");
 63 
 64             GUILayout.Space(10);
 65             GUILayout.EndVertical();
 66 
 67             scroll = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll);
 68             for (int i = 0; i < listResult.Count; i++)
 69             {
 70                 GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
 71                 GUILayout.Label(listResult[i], GUILayout.Width(position.width * 0.68f));
 72                 GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
 73                 if (GUILayout.Button("Open Scene", GUILayout.Width(position.width * 0.30f)))
 74                 {
 75                     string[] tokens = listResult[i].Split(' ');
 76                     EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(scenesPathNames[int.Parse(tokens[0])], OpenSceneMode.Single);
 77                     //Selection.activeGameObject = objectsList[i];
 78                 }
 79                 GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
 80             }
 81             GUILayout.EndScrollView();
 82         }
 83     }
 84 
 85 
 86      void DoSearch()
 87     {
 88         scenesPathNames = GetAllScenesPaths(ref scenesNames);
 89         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 90 
 91         for (int i = 0; i < scenesPathNames.Length; i++)
 92         {
 93             GetSceneObjects(ref objectsList, scenesPathNames[i], OpenSceneMode.Single);
 94             
 95             foreach (GameObject obj in objectsList)
 96             {
 97 
 98                 int numOfColl = 0;
 99                 foreach (Collider2D collider in obj.GetComponents<Collider2D>())
100                 {
101                     numOfColl++;
102                     
103                 }
104 
105 
106                 //simulating scene load
107                 numOfColl += CheckForAdditionalRuntimeColliders(obj);
108 
109 
110 
111                 if (numOfColl > 1)
112                 {
113                     builder.Clear();
114                     builder.Append($"{i} Scene Name: {scenesNames[i]}\t\t");
115                     builder.Append($"Object Name: {obj.name}");
116                     builder.Append($"\t\tColliders:{numOfColl}");
117                     listResult.Add(builder.ToString());
118                 }
119             }
120         }
121     }
122 
123 
124     private void GetSceneObjects(ref List<GameObject> objectsList, string sceneName, OpenSceneMode open_mode)
125     { 
126         List<GameObject> temp_list = new List<GameObject>();
127         objectsList = new List<GameObject>();
128 
129         Scene scene = EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(sceneName, open_mode);
130         scene.GetRootGameObjects(temp_list);
131         for (int i = 0; i < temp_list.Count; i++)
132         {
133             objectsList.Add(temp_list[i]);
134         }
135         
136     }
137 
138     private static string[] GetAllScenesPaths(ref string[] sceneNames)
139     {
140         List<string> temp = new List<string>();
141         List<string> tempNames = new List<string>();
142         foreach (UnityEditor.EditorBuildSettingsScene S in UnityEditor.EditorBuildSettings.scenes)
143         {
144             if (S.enabled)
145             {
146                 string path = S.path;
147                 string name = S.path.Substring(S.path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
148                 name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 6);
149                 temp.Add(path);
150                 tempNames.Add(name);
151             }
152         }
153         sceneNames = tempNames.ToArray();
154         return temp.ToArray();
155     }
156 
229 }
```

Comment: How about in your function which iterates through all the scenes, when the SceneManager.sceneLoaded, you add a monobehaviour gameObject into the tree, and its Update() function (during its very first cycle) triggers the 2d collider component count, and hands it back to the scene iterator to continue to the next scene? As Update() is called after Start(), it should enforce the proper waiting for all Starts to have added their potential 2d colliders.

Comment: I would no make the script enter Playmode but rather simply only run your script in Playmode ;)